# How to send multiple emails in the background?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET. I am implementing a forum and I have a comment submission form. When the user submits the comment, the system sends an email to all registered users that a comment has been added to the website. The system is sending multiple emails using a loop and I am connecting with the Gmail server and sending the emails one by one. The problem is that the more registered users you have, the longer the user has to wait until all the emails have been sent and a confirmation message appears on the screen.

Is there a way how to send emails without having the user waiting until all emails have been sent on submission?

Comment: Sounds like you need an asychronous process. There are many examples for .Net asynchronous coding that should help you.

Comment: Take a look at [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: You could also configure your database to send the emails. [Check this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't send the e-mails from the ASP.Net application, because that costs time, as you've noticed yourself.

I would create a database table named `Emails`. The ASP.Net application would only generate rows, but not send the e-mails itself.

Create a console application, whose sole purpose is generating e-mails from the `Emails`-table. Use the Windows Taskscheduler to run this console application every (for instance 5) minutes.