# auto sending mails by server at specific intervals

Tags: email, c#-4.0, triggers

I am looking for some code, which I could send mails out of my website.

I want the user's registered in my website, to be able to automatically send emails at specific time, that's defined by the user. I need a triggering mechanism in asp.NET such that it fires the exact date & time as specified by the user

Any suggestions/approach apart from the above statement is also welcomed.

***I have found a solution for the problem, and would kindly request the moderators to delete the post.
Thank you***

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307081/how-to-send-multiple-emails-in-the-background

Answer (score 2):

Asp.Net is not the correct framework to perform scheduled tasks.
You *can* use Asp.Net for a web interface in which you allow the users to create "tasks", set the timed intervals and even the content of the emails.
BUT - The process which sends the emails should probably be done using a [task scheduler](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2005/10/24/428303.aspx)...

[Here is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390307/windows-service-vs-scheduled-task) to point you in the right direction...